# Hiding Tab Bar and adding toolbar at that location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar

I am developing a tab Bar based Application.On a particular view controller I have to hide the tab Bar and add toolBar there.What I did is 
`self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;` to hide the tab Bar.The tab bar is hidden properly but the tool Bar is not showing at that location.the space of tabBar is showing blank and toolBar is coming up.Please tell me how to sort out this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are pushing your viewcontroller(having no tabbar) add the line:

yourviewcontroller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;

Hope it helps....

Comment: sorry I have already tried this .it does not work.Please suggest some other idea.

Comment: written only this for hiding tabbar self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;